# Relations between the attributes in same table

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I'm making a table of words list. This would be something like this.

```
| id | words    | 
.................
|1   | good     |
|2   | bad      |
|3   |benificial|
|4   | big      |
|5   | adept    |
```

I need to find the similar words from the table. For example **good** , **beneficial** and **adept** are similar words. While searching a word **good** from a MySQL query I need to find similar words to it. A word can have more than one similar word from the table. How can I implement this? Please help.

Update: If I search the word **adept**, I should get **good**, **beneficial** as the result. For example, I want to show similar words to my web page when a word is searched through a search form that would appear as follow.

If good is searched through the form then,

Good: beneficial, adept

If beneficial is searched then,

Beneficial: good, adept.

If bad is searched then relevant similar words to bad would be displayed. The number of similar words is  not limited (ie all the similar words from the database should be displayed.)

Comment: Does column words contains more than one word? would you share us some example of your data?

Comment: I think my question is somehow misleading. It should have been relations between the same attributes in a table. I have edited the post and I hope it is clearer. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a RelatedWords table like this

```
| WordId | RelatedWordId    |
.............................
|1       | 3                |
|1       | 5                |
```

Then WHERE by the WordId. You can have the ids of related words as result.

Comment: Doesn't this makes the table even larger. For example when I have to search the word **adept** it should show **good** and **beneficial**. Same goes to other words.

Comment: @Sajit Khadka: This doesn't make "the table" larger. This is an *additional* table. And yes, it has more entries than the words table: good->beneficial, good->adept, beneficial->good, ... But why are you so worried about table size? The times when a hard disk had only some 10 MB or so are long gone.

Comment: Words have different meanings according to different contexts. For example, *good* can be a noun (the good that is stocked in bin 17). How do you handle this?

Answer (score 0):

You need a table for word groups, in other words: a synonyms table.

**words table**

```
id | word
---+-----
1  | good
2  | fair
3  | just
4  | pretty
```

**synonyms table**

```
groupkey | id_word
---------+--------
GOOD     | 1
GOOD     | 2
GOOD     | 3
PRETTY   | 2
PRETTY   | 4
```

I used text here for the groupkey so as to get over the idea a bit clearer, but you can of course just use some number with no inherent meaning instead.

Comment: Aren't the words in the groupkey repeating? Wouldn't the synonyms table be too long If there are 1000s of words ?

Comment: Yes, of course, words are repeating here. "fair" can mean "good" or it can mean "pretty", but "good" and "pretty" don't mean the same. So "fair" is twice in the table, once in the "good" group, once in the "pretty" group. A table doesn't get "too long"; it gets as big as needed for the data to store. Don't worry about that. (And after all, I assume such a synonyms table to be about, say, four times as big as the words table, as not every word has several meanings.)